# Querying nested KeyProperties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the following models:

```
class Company(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    # some other fields

class User(polymodel.PolyModel):
    company = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Company)
    # some other fields

class Object(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    # some other fields
```

Now I have a `user` and I want to query `Objects` that are associated with other `Users` in the same company like this:

```
Object.query(Object.user.company == user.company)
```

Of course, this doesn't work, since `Object.user` is a key and I cannot access anything beyond that.

Is there any way to do it? I only need the company key, I was thinking on a `ComputedProperty` but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. Also, it would be better to query based on any field in `company`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to denormalize and store redundant information, as the datastore doesn't support joins.

For instance  given your models above, a user can only be a member of one company, if you really need to search all objects whose user is a member of a particular company then store the company key in the Object.

Use a computed property if that works best for you.

Alternately use a factory that always takes the User as a argument and construct Object that way.